# How to fix firebase update password?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am using react native version 0.72 and expo version 49.0.15 and I have a screen that handle changing of password, but when the users try to update their passwords, the app close on its own.

In the screen, I have 3 inputs where the user can input their old password, new password and repeat new password.

When a button is clicked, a function is called to handle the changing of passwords. Here's my code:

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState('');

const savePassword = () => {

    const creds = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);

    auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(creds)
    .then(() => {
        auth().currentUser.updatePassword(newPassword)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('password successfully updated.');
        });
    });

}
```

In simulator, 'password successfully updated.' appears, so I believe that means, the password was changed. but when I tried to re-login using the new password, it just won't work, old password one does.

In the actual device, the app just exited on its own and didn't change the password.

Comment: There is something wrong with the synchronization. Firebase API is asynchronous and you need to keep that in mind when writing code or try to access your firebase database.  I guess Rainy sidewalks answer will be correct, because it uses the await pattern.

Comment: @Iskandir it still didn't work. I remember that I tried this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with `await`

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState('');

const savePassword = async () => {

    const creds = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);

   const reAuthResult =await auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(creds)
    .then(async () => {
       await auth().currentUser.updatePassword(newPassword)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('password successfully updated.');
        });
    });

}
```

let me know any

**2nd approch**

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState('');

const savePassword = async () => {
  try {
    const creds = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);

    await auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(creds);

    await auth().currentUser.updatePassword(newPassword);

    console.log('Password successfully updated.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error updating password:', error);
  }
};
```

Comment: I changed my code like that and it is still the same, like nothing changed.

Comment: log out and login then try ...

Comment: also better if you can use cnsole.log to see exactly at which line the block is being terminated (if it is )

Comment: it still didn't work. I remember that I also tried that.

Comment: ok can you share the log result from the console  ?

Comment: The console outputs the "password successfully updated.", but when I try to login again. Only the old password works.

Comment: try the 2nd and let me know

Comment: It is now working. I just misspelled a variable name after updating. Thank you.